# Lispy code? Prime factors of a number

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, factors

My answer to [Project Euler problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) *(largest prime factor of 600851475143)* is below.

Please suggest improvements, style changes, indentation, commenting, naming of "objects", ...

```
(defun factors (n)
    "return a list with prime factors of n"
    (let ((result))
        (loop while (zerop (rem n 2))           ; do 2
              do (loop while (zerop (rem n 2))
                       do (setf n (/ n 2))
                       do (setf result (cons 2 result))))
        (loop for i from 3 by 2                 ; do 3, 5, 7, 9, ...
              while (>= n (* i i))              ; until square root of what's left of n
              do (loop while (zerop (rem n i))
                       do (setf n (/ n i))
                       do (setf result (cons i result))))
        (if (= n 1) result (cons n result))))   ; if n is not 1 it is also a factor
```

Questions:

1. Is the `(let ((result)) #| ... (setf result ...) ... |# result)` construction acceptable?
2. I like the result as it is, *in reverse*; but, other than `(reverse result)` is there a way to `collect` factors **into** result? My attempts with `collect i` (or `collect i into result`) would not compile.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, except for a few nitpicks.

1. Use [`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm) instead of `(setf x (conx y x))` for readability.
2. Use [`floor`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_floorc.htm) instead of `rem` + `/` for efficiency.
3. 1st and 3rd `loop`s are identical, so they should be abstracted into a local [`flet`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm) function.
4. Use [`nreverse`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm) instead of `reverse` for the return value.  Yes, you can avoid that by using `collect` combined with [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) but it makes little sense in your specific case.

Comment: Thank you. I still gotta learn how to use functions that return two values. Now working on that `flet` suggestion.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781 for multi-valued functions

Answer (score 1):

After direct feedback on [sds's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244128/2842) my code is now

```
(defun factors (n)
    "return a list with prime factors of n"
    (let ((result))
        (flet ((transfer-factor (fac)
                "transfer available fac from number `n` to list `result`"
                (loop with quotient and remainder
                      do (setf (values quotient remainder)
                               (floor n fac))
                      while (zerop remainder)
                      do (setf n quotient)
                      do (push fac result))))
            (transfer-factor 2)             ; do 2
            (loop for i from 3 by 2         ; do 3, 5, 7, 9, ...
                  while (>= n (* i i))      ; until sqrt of what's left of n
                  do (transfer-factor i)))
        (when (> n 1) (push n result))      ; n may still be a factor
        result))                            ; return complete list

;; in the repl use
;; (first (factors 600851475143))
```

Incorporated using `floor` to get quotient and remainder in one operation, incorporated the `flet` *inner function*.

I learned to use `values` and a lot more about the `loop` construct.
Thanks @sds